# FB graph: can't retrieve facebook user image any more

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When you use this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fb_user_id/picture?height=600&redirect=false
```

you'll see json like:

```
{
   "data": {
      "height": 720,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p720x720/13001320_100996553638879_478536659476895885_n.jpg?oh=ec91a8418298a51403eaa306f62f9ab3&oe=58C0E384",
      "width": 720
   }
}
```

Until before some days I could download the image with:

```
$array = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?height=600&redirect=false');
$array = json_decode($array,true);

$image = file_get_contents($array['data']['url']);
file_put_contents($bildname, $image);
```

But now I cant do that :(

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

shows: `bool(false)`

Any ideas?

Comment: What does Facebook return to you?

Comment: yeah, you need to do a var_dump before json_decode. debug the response.

Comment: the bool(false) is the var_dump before json_decode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with curl:

```
 function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?height=600&redirect=false');
$array = json_decode($returned_content,true);
```